# How to Adjust Position of tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I want to create a tkinter canvas anchored at the top, left corner of my screen, but the canvas is defaulting to a different location on my screen. Here is an image of this happening:

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ij5l.png)

Here is my current code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import tkinter
 from tkinter import *
 from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Infrared Camera Interface")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)



class MyApp:
  def __init__(self, parent):

    self.C = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="white", height=560, width=450)


    #Set the dimensions of the window
    parent.minsize(width=600, height=600)
    parent.maxsize(width=600, height=600)


    #Prepare the image object being loaded into the stream camera
    self.imgName = 'Dish.png'
    self.img = Image.open(self.imgName)
    self.img = self.img.resize((560, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS)     

    #Display the image onto the stream
    self.displayimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

    self.C.create_image(0,0,image = self.displayimg, anchor = NW)

    self.C.pack()

myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I anchor this canvas to the top, left corner of the screen?

Comment: read how to use `place()` -  [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). You can also use `grid()` instead of `place()` - [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: I have, but when I use the code: self.C.place(x=0,y=0) to orient the canvas in the top, left corner, it remains in its same location.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `pack()` - [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm). Better not mix `pack()`, `grid()` and `place()`

Comment: try `self.C.pack(anchor='w')`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'm a bit new to tkinter.

Comment: see image: https://imgur.com/uUZwYXi or older version but with source code - at the end of page http://blog.furas.pl/wyrownywanie-widgetow-tekstow-na-widgecie-i-linii-w-tekscie-w-tkinter.html

Comment: have you read any documentation? `pack`, `place`, and `grid` are all fairly well documented, with many options for definition where the widget should go.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using grid() as opposed to pack() because in the long run, grid will give you a lot more customization as your program gets more pieces.

grid() for this program would look like this:

```
self.C.grid(row=0, column = 0, rowspan = 0, columnspan = 0, sticky='nsew')
```

notes - "sticky='nsew'" means that the image will be oriented in north south east west, and honestly, I haven't seen it written any other way.

now of course, "rowspan" and "columnspan" are not necessary for only one image, but if you would like to put several things either next to or under this image, those will come in handy

Comment: I don't think `grid` gives you any more customization than `pack`. Both have strengths and weaknesses, and neither is better in all circumstances.